# Adding new column after column and defining a default

Tags: mysql, database, alter-table

I am trying to add a column after another column while also specifying a default value. Below is my attempt that does not work.

```
alter table pageareas add content_userDefined BIT( 1 ) NULL default 0 after content;
```

If I remove "after content" it works:

```
alter table pageareas add content_userDefined BIT( 1 ) NULL default 0;
```

And if I remove "default 0" it works:

```
alter table pageareas add content_userDefined BIT( 1 ) NULL after content;
```

How can I accomplish adding it after a specified column while also defining a default value?

I am using MySql 5.1.36

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm reading the [documentation for `alter table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) correctly this time... you're only able to specify `after` or `default`, but not both.  You could work around this by creating the column using `after`, and then altering it to have the `default`:

```
alter table pageareas add content_userDefined BIT( 1 ) NULL after content;
alter table pageareas alter content_userDefined set default 0;
```